# Implementing last with foldr1

Tags: haskell, fold

I've a problem with implementing the last function using foldr1. I assume that it takes the right most element and treats it like the accumulator value, then applies binary function to the accumulator and its neighbor until it reaches the beginning of a given list. However, the code shown below doesn't work. Could someone tell me what's wrong with it? Instead of returning the last element it prints out the first one

```
last' list = foldr1 (\acc _ -> acc) list
```

Comment: You need to return the second argument, not the first.

Comment: but why? i'm using foldr1 not foldl1

Comment: the second element is the accumulated value - the order of traversal changes and order of the parameters change too ...

Answer (score 1):

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

As you can see, foldr makes the accumulator the second argument, while the value from the list is the first. foldr1 behaves the same way. So, as Lee said, you need to have your lamdba return the second argument rather than the first. Alternatively, you could say `foldr1 (flip const)`

Comment: `flip const` not `seq`, it'd be very weird to force elements just to get the last one.

Comment: `foldr1 seq` and `foldr1 (\_ acc -> acc)` have different semantics though. All of the thunks in the list will be forced if you use `foldr1 seq` but that's not the case with `foldr1 (\_ acc -> acc)`. This could be an important difference if it takes a very long time to evaluate each element of the list. Also, if there are any bottoms in `xs`, `foldr1 seq xs` is bottom as well (which could be bad).